# Counting and conditional probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We put $r$ balls in $m$ boxes. What's the probability that box $1$ will have exactly $k$ balls?

My guess is 
$\dfrac{r \choose k}{m^r}$ probability 
because there are $m^r$ ways of putting the balls in boxes and $\dbinom{r}{k}$ ways of picking $k$ balls. I'm not totally convinced of this though because it seems like this may be the probability for at least $k$ balls rather than exact? and. I saw a few other similar examples that weren't the same but still didn't make complete sense to me. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: what if $m=1$ and $r=k+1$?

Comment: touché. I hadn't considered the excess of r in this scenario. I'm realizing this is much more complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider also the number of ways the remaining $r-k$ balls go into the remaining $m-1$ boxes.  This can be done with [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets):

$$P(k) = \frac{{r \choose k}{m-2+r-k \choose m-2}}{m^r}.$$

**Edit:**  Some explanation of the extra term.  From the link, one way to count multisets is to line up the objects to divide up, and insert dividers where the sets fall.  To divide the objects into $n$ sets, we'll need $n-1$ dividers.  Then, counting the ways $N(j,n)$ to divide $j$ objects into $n$ sets involves counting the places to put the $n-1$ dividers amongst $j+n-1$ locations:

$$N(j,n) = {j+n-1 \choose n-1}.$$

Substituting $m-1$ for $n$ and $r-k$ for $j$ gives the extra term.

Comment: So why do m-2 and not m-1 then?

Comment: Edited my answer to explain more.